# Vertical border 100% height not working. Why?

Tags: html, css, height, border, zurb-foundation

I'm currently designing this template - [link](http://creativusmouse.com/html/blog.html) - and came up with an annoying problem:
I've been trying, for the last 3 hours, to figure out a way of getting the vertical border line of the main content to be 100% height but somehow it just doesn't work and it keeps getting that gap between the vertical line and the footer. 
I'm building this with foundation-zurb 4 framework so it contains multiple css files however I tried to make it as simple as possible. You can download the files here - [link 2](http://creativusmouse.com/html.zip) - if you need to. 
I hope this is not too much to ask...

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: are you referring to the line that is to the left of the archives but it doesn't ends meeting the footer, right!?

Comment: ok...have some patience, i'll try to work it out.

Comment: @user1628193 it can be solved with css but you need to change your code somehow and use `display:inline-table` for `row` DIV and `display:inline-block` for DIV of class `large-9`. and some more change. but its better to use a simple jQuery as i say in my answer to solve this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this to set the main container height equal to it's parent height(the row div height).
it's better to use this some where in your footer:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $('document').ready(function(){
      var parentHeight = $('div.large-9').parent().height();
      $('div.large-9').height(parentHeight);
   });
</script>
```

**UPDATE**
as i checked your website you need to remove this border on small windows size so add this to your css file:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 740px){
    .container.right-border {
       border-right: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked! WOW Amazing! Thank you so much!!
Just one more thing - Is it possible to disable this when seeing the page on a mobile phone or tablet?
Thank you!

Comment: @user1628193 yes! i'm going to update my answer to support this. check it out

Comment: Great stuff. Just checked it and worked fine. Thanks al lot once again!

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the one shown in the screen shot. Actually the `<div class="large-9 columns container right-border">` has the right border which causes the border to end along with the content. Remove the right border and add the left border to the following div `<div class="large-3 columns sidebar" style="border-left: 1px solid #dedede;">` the screen shot of result is also attached here.

[image]

Comment: Hi. Thanks but when the main content contains another post I keep getting the same problem...